# Proving that $ (A + I)^n=(2^n-1)A + I $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

Assume that  $ A^2 = A$ , where $A$ is  a square matrix.

> Then prove $(A + I)^n=(2^n-1)A + I $

Could someone help ?

Comment: Induction${}{}$?

Comment: Or binominal theorem?

Comment: In the book he said nothing, but I believe it is induction

Comment: Prove by hand the cases $n\le 3$ and surely you'll have find solution for the general case on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for all $n\ge 1$ we have $A^n = A$ and hence 
$$(A + I)^n=  \sum_{j=0}^{n}{n\choose j}A^j=I+A\sum_{j=1}^{n}{n\choose j}1^j=(2^n-1)A + I$$

Or By induction for $n=1$ the result follows.

Assume $$(A + I)^n=(2^n-1)A + I$$
then 
$$(A + I)^{n+1} = (A + I)^n (A + I) = ((2^n-1)A + I)(A + I) \\=(2^n-1)A + I  +(2^n-1)A^2 + A \\= (2^n-1)A + I  +(2^n-1)A + A \\= (2^n-1)A + I  +2^nA \\=(2^{n+1}-1)A + I   $$

Answer (score 4):

$A$ and $I$ commute, hence the binomial theorem (for matrices) gives
$$(A+I)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k} A^{n-k}I^k$$

$$= I + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n \choose k}A \tag{1}$$

$$= I + (2^n - 1)A \tag{2}$$

$(1)$

see comment

$(2)$

$2^n = (1+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}$

Comment: Sisyphus, how did you get the $I +$ in step 2?

Comment: @BCLC Why did you edit this?

Comment: Sisyphus, to make explicit the $I+$

Comment: @BCLC Your edit butchers a one sentence proof into ten lines.

Comment: Sisyphus, fine. Thanks for the feedback. Here we go: $(1)$

$$(A+I)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k} A^{n-k}I^k$$

$$= A^{n-n}I^n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n \choose k} A^{n-k}I^k$$

$$= A^{n-n}I + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n \choose k} A^{n-k}I^k$$

$$= A^{n-n} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n \choose k} A^{n-k}I^k$$

$$= A^{0} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n \choose k} A^{n-k}I^k$$

$$= I + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n \choose k} A^{n-k}I^k$$

$$= I + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n \choose k} A^{n-k}I$$

$$= I + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n \choose k} A^{n-k}$$

$$= I + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n \choose k} A$$

Answer (score 1):

By indution if $(A+I)^n=(2^n-1)A+I$ and $A^2=A$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
(A+I)^{n+1}&=&(A+I)^n(A+I)=((2^n-1)A+I)(A+I)\\
&=&(2^n-1)A^2+A+(2^n-1)A+I\\
&=&2(2^n-1)A+A+I\\
&=&(2^{n+1}-2)A+A+I\\
&=&(2^{n+1}-1)A+I
\end{eqnarray}